# Jest spyOn Array.prototype.push function - how can I spy it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a private property in the class where I keep array of Objects

```
class myClass {
   private objects: any = [];
   public addObject(object: any): any {
      objects.push(object);
   }
}
```

I want to test in jest if push was called.
How can I do it?
My current implementation does not work.

```
describe('myClass ', () => {
   test('should add object to objects array', () => {
      const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(Array.prototype, 'push');
      const obj = new myClass();

      obj.addObject({fakeObj})

      expect(pushSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
   }
}
```

Comment: Why? You should be testing the behavior, not the implementation.

Comment: Your test would be better, if `objects`' value is exposed. You should check whether a new value has been added to `objects` instead of spying on the array's push method.

Comment: You are right however I can not check if objects was added because this is a private property. I do not want to cast as any myClass in order to access to private properties. My implementation does not need get method for objects as well. So how can I test it? From my point of view I should not adjust class for test but test for class. There is no reason to change private property to public property from application perspective.

Answer (score 2):

`private` keyword is only for TypeScript, not for JavaScript. After compiling, the property/method access modifiers will be erased. You can still access them with a dot and with square brackets. In order to ignore the type check of TSC, we use square brackets way.

`index.ts`:

```js
export class MyClass {
  private objects: any = [];
  public addObject(object: any): any {
    this.objects.push(object);
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { MyClass } from './';

describe('60507395', () => {
  it('should add object', () => {
    const myClass = new MyClass();
    const pushSpy = jest.spyOn(myClass['objects'], 'push');
    myClass.addObject({});
    expect(pushSpy).toBeCalledWith({});
    expect(myClass['objects']).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60507395/index.test.ts (9.733s)
  60507395
    ✓ should add object (4ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.604s
```

Comment: Thanks @slideshowp2 and is it right way to perform a tests? Should we check private properties by checking itself explicitly? Or should we check it using public functions (somehow)?